# Restkit: Retry failed request

Tags: ios, web-services, delegates, restkit

Using Restkit, I want to retry a request that has failed. I am trying to do this from the delegate method as follows:

```
-(void)request:(RKRequest *)request didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error{
    NSLog(error.domain);
    NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",error.code]);
    NSLog(error.localizedDescription);
    NSLog(error.localizedFailureReason);
    [request cancel];
    [request reset];
    [request send];
}
```

However, I get the following error:

```
2013-01-14 11:19:29.423 Mobile_ACPL[7893:907] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Attempting to add the same request multiple times'
```

How can I make this happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message implies that the `request` your are trying to (re-)send is still on some internal queues. Possibly, giving the system more time to process `cancel` and `reset` could make things work.

Try with this:

```
-(void)request:(RKRequest *)request didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error{

  [request cancel];
  [request reset];

  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_current_queue(), ^() {
      [request send];
  }
}
```

Hope it helps. If this does not work, then possibly delaying a bit the (re-)sending might help. This would amount to doing (for 1.0 sec delay):

```
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, NSEC_PER_SEC * 1.0),
               dispatch_get_current_queue(),  ^() {
      [request send];
  });
```

Or making a `copy` of the request altogether and sending that.

Comment: Note that `dispatch_get_current_queue()` is deprecated since iOS 6.0